# How to hide fullscreen window header line in MacOS app?

Tags: swift, macos

My problem is header of window in fullscreen mode.

When I move cursor to the top of screen I see the following:

[image]

But I want to see the following:

[image]

Hiding of buttons is not a problem:

```
wnd.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
wnd.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
wnd.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
```

but how to hide the line?

Google say nothing about this =(

Maybe there is some sort of additional "safe zone area" that must be disabled in another way?

---

```
WindowGroup {
    SomeView()
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

}
.windowStyle( HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle() )
```

hides only titlebar from windowed mode, but not from fullscreen

The code:

```
 NSApp?.mainWindow?.styleMask.insert(NSWindow.StyleMask.unifiedTitleAndToolbar)        
 NSApp?.mainWindow?.styleMask.insert(NSWindow.StyleMask.fullSizeContentView)        
 NSApp?.mainWindow?.styleMask.insert(NSWindow.StyleMask.titled)
NSApp?.mainWindow?.toolbar?.isVisible = false
NSApp?.mainWindow?.titleVisibility = .hidden
NSApp?.mainWindow?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
```

also do nothing with header line in fullscreen mode

Comment: From the very bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49697684/3791245): `window?.styleMask.remove(.titled)`?  Note the comment on the answer, where somebody suggests you have to insert the `.titled` attribute first, and then later call `.remove(.titled)`.

Comment: @SeanSkell it crashing my app https://prnt.sc/26ay8l4

Comment: Have you seen any other app hide the bar that way? I believe the buttons are supposed to be there to exit fullscreen?

Comment: @de. as truly I need to remove exactly line, but to leave buttons on those place. I need titless window. Because of I need to realize custom title line that will be different in fullscreen mode from windowed mode. But this "native" title line hides my custom title line.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug. There is no workaround found for this issue (just file a bug to Apple), but you might find useful to disable menubar at all by returning only `[.fullscreen]` in below callback of window delegate (if you have access to NSWindow instance) and add, say, own floating control panel on full-screen (just idea).

```
class WindowDelegate: NSObject, NSWindowDelegate {
    func window(_ window: NSWindow, willUseFullScreenPresentationOptions proposedOptions: NSApplication.PresentationOptions = []) -> NSApplication.PresentationOptions {
        return [.fullScreen]
    }
}
```

*Note: alternate way to change application options is via `NSApp` (just in case), like*

```
NSApp.presentationOptions = [.hideMenuBar, .hideDock]
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the title bar entirely, use `NSWindow.StyleMask.Borderless`.

Note, by default this also disables the `canBecomeKey` and `canBecomeMain` properties which you will need to change back to `true` or else various other things won't work properly (for example, keyboard input).

I'm not sure if an existing window can become a borderless window. I vaguely recall something about having to create a new window (or enable the flag in the storyboard).

You also won't have a full screen button anymore, so entering and exiting will have to be done programatically.

Comment: in case of swiftUI app where I need to make window Borderless? Inside of appDelegate? In which one method?

Comment: In my question I have tried to do this : "wnd.styleMask.insert(NSWindow.StyleMask.borderless)" but it didn't do anything